# sql injection example

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I'm newer in sql and I would like to learn about SQL Injection. For example, I have a simple sql query like using POST (php):

```
    $valuedata = $_POST['name1'];
    $dbase->query("SELECT * FROM tabledata WHERE value LIKE '%$valuedata%'");
```

How to protect this query of SQL Injection?

Comment: Take a look at prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: $_POST['name1'] = "'; DROP TABLE users;"

Comment: If possible, give me a simple example for my query, please in php language

Comment: $valuedata = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name1']); 
$dbase->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value LIKE '%$valuedata%' LIMIT 1");

Please control me, is it true?